# Contributing to angular compiler

Tags: angular, open-source

I was trying to fix a bug in angular-core repository. I have build the project with bazel successfully on my local and got a `dist/` folder.

I want to `debug` this file, For example: Add some `console.log()` statements to print values of variables.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/parse_util.ts

What is the best way to debug code of this file. I am using `tsc filename` and then tryting to run the compiled js via `Node.js`.
I am getting errors as the compiles js contains `import` and `export` statements not supported by Node.js.

Any Angular Core developer who can give me some help in it. I will be very thankful to him.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `ts-node` (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), to execute the file.

Something like this should work:

```
ts-node index.js --inspect
```

Use the output to debug the application in chrome.